# Regarding ownership of computer program source-code shared in an answer on a Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, legal, licensing, attribution

I have active accounts on various Stack Exchange sites falling under Technology domain. Due to the nature of the domain, often the posted answers in part or whole, requires me to to write some form of source-code in a programming or scripting language. The code is almost always originally composed, and is not copied from elsewhere.

I am aware of how the content posted on Stack Exchange sites is [licensed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing), (*Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike*). From [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) post on Stack Overflow blog, I understand that any republishing of content requires attribution.

However, I am curious to learn how this affects just the source-code written by me as part (or whole) of the answer? It's fairly obvious that it is also covered under the same CC license terms.

Is attribution expected, if I wish to share the source-code elsewhere publicly using my personal account(s)? Most common scenarios are including it in a public repository (such as on GitHub), personal blog post, forum post etc.

To reiterate, I am talking only about the source code written by myself in my own answers.

Comment: I think this has been asked before, but the license applies to OTHERS using your content. You as the copyright owner can do whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

On a semi-ironic note, I’m going to republish/remix something I originally wrote for [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386060/6083675):

When you post on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange your content is licensed under [CC by-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), no matter if it’s code or text. This means that *anyone* can remix your content for any reason as long as they give [proper attribution to you](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). However, the license is "non-exclusive", which means that you, as the owner of the content, can also license your content on other sites without *needing* to properly attribute yourself. All sites I’ve checked license the content as non-exclusive, which means it’s ok you’re reposting something.

See for example  [Medium’s ToS](https://medium.com/policy/medium-terms-of-service-9db0094a1e0f).

On a non-legal note, I always attribute myself when I repost text, but for something that was entirely code it would be annoying and I wouldn’t be likely to do it. Attributing yourself has the perk of quelling any potential accusations of plagiarism though (even though you’d be in the right).